# How can I solve "Local path doesn't exist." error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I created a new project in Android Studio 1.1 and I built successfully. After that, I added a jar libraries and updated build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-gson-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar')
}
```

Now, I am getting error "Local path doesn't exist."
I search other questions about this problem but I can't solve it. Help me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added jar libraries, your Gradle file should have updated itself correctly. `Local path doesn't exist` means that one of the files you want to compile is not in the path you have specified.

Comment: Thanks. I had not realized. I removed libraries like @Ishrat said and I changed packagingOptions in build.gradle. It works.

Answer (score 0):

If you used

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Then no need to add each `.jar` file one by one ,it means you have to remvoe following form your `build.gradle`.

```
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-gson-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar')
```